# Missing LaTeX fonts used in Anki. Where can I find libertineMono-type1?

Tags: fonts, miktex, anki

I use the flashcard program Anki which allows math equations to be written with LaTeX.

I've run into an error where the file `'libertineMono-type1.sty'` cannot be found.
For context, the equation I'm trying to render is `$y=x$`

Here are some more details.

The `tmp.log` file that shows the error message reads:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7) (preloaded format=latex 2020.8.24)  24 AUG 2020 10:59
entering extended mode
**./tmp.tex
(tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\utf8x.def"
File: utf8x.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\ucs.sty"
Package: ucs 2013/05/11 v2.2 UCS: Unicode input support

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\uni-global.def"
File: uni-global.def 2013/05/13 UCS: Unicode global data
)
\uc@secondtry=\count176
\uc@combtoks=\toks17
\uc@combtoksb=\toks18
\uc@temptokena=\toks19
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine-type1\libertine-type1.sty"
Package: libertine-type1 2012/10/27 (autoinst) Style file for LinuxLibertineO.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontaxes\fontaxes.sty"
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks20
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks21

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count177
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biolinium-type1\biolinum-type1.sty"
Package: biolinum-type1 2012/10/30 (autoinst) Style file for LinuxBiolinumO.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsu on input line 17.
)

! LaTeX Error: File `libertineMono-type1.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.1 ...usepackage{libertineMono-type1} \usepackage
                                                  [libertine]{newtxmath} \re...
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1105 strings out of 481175
 17175 string characters out of 2914384
 258573 words of memory out of 3000000
 16757 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 536150 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,0n,35p,882b,38s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Checking Anki's TeX output, it reads:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\special{papersize=3in,5in} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{libertine-type1} 
\usepackage{biolinum-type1} 
\usepackage{libertineMono-type1} 
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{color} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{wasysym} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0in} \newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}} \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,130,255} \begin{document}
$y=x$
\end{document}
```

which has a console output that reads

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/parag/AppData/Local/Temp/anki_temp/tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\utf8x.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\ucs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\uni-global.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine-type1\libertine-type1.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontaxes\fontaxes.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex")))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biolinium-type1\biolinum-type1.sty")

! LaTeX Error: File `libertineMono-type1.sty' not found.
```

I also have libertine, libertinegc, libertinus, libertinus-fonts, libertinus-otf, libertinus-type1, and libertinust1math installed in MiKTeX, which are the only font packages I have related to the libertine font family. I also manually installed libertine-type1 and biolinium-type1 with a local `texmf` tree.

I can't really find the libertineMono-type1 font anywhere, so I'm not sure what to do.
Any help would be great!

Comment: your template looks quite outdated, e.g. libertine-type1 is obsolete, https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine-type1, and as you say libertineMono-type1 doesn't exist. You should try to update it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `\usepackage[type1]{libertine}` to load the Type 1 versions of Libertine, Biolinum and Libertine Mono.

Otherwise, load `\usepackage[type1]{libertineRoman, biolinum, libertineMono}`.  This file is part of the `libertine` package on CTAN.

You can eliminate the `[type1]` option to load `fontspec` and the OpenType versions of the fonts on LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

The file `libertinusMono-type1.sty` was added to the `libertine` package [back in 2013,](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.8030.1360915229.2390.ctan-ann@dante.de) and seems to have been removed at some point since then without the change ever having been noted in any changelog.

Comment: Where in ANKI, can you write \usepackage[type1]{libertine} ?

Comment: @Jean-Pat I suggest you try replacing the lines `\usepackkage(libertine-type1}`, `\usepackage{biolinum-type1}` and `\usepackage{libertineMono-type1}` with that line. I have not tested it in Anki, but it should be installed on MikTeX, but if Anki maintains its own TeX tree, I don't know the precise command to install a package to it. Copying over the files from CTAN probably would work.

Comment: I succeeded in writing \usepackkage(libertine-type1} in the card header from the ANKI app menu: Tools>handle note ("gérer les notes" in french menu).